# How can I override a Spring Data REST method without disabling default implementations

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I finally found a way to override methods of Spring Data REST with a custom implementation. Unfortunately this disables the default handling.

My Repository should contain `findAll` and `findById` exposed over the `GET: /games` and `GET: /games/{id}` respectively and `save` should not be exported because it is overriden by the controller.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "games", exported = true)
public interface GameRepository extends Repository<Game, UUID> {
    Collection<Game> findAll();

    Game findById(UUID id);

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    Game save(Game game);
}
```

My controller should handle `POST: /games`, generate the game on the server and return the saved Game.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@ExposesResourceFor(Game.class)
@RequestMapping("games")
public class CustomGameController {
    private final GameService gameService;

    public CustomGameController(GameService gameService) {
        this.gameService = gameService;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/hal+json")
    public PersistentEntityResource generateNewGame(@RequestBody CreateGameDTO createGameDTO, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
        Game game = gameService.generateNewGame(createGameDTO);
        return assembler.toFullResource(game);
    }

}
```

However when I try to `GET: /games` it returns `405: Method Not Allowed` but `POST: /games` works as intended. When I change the value of the generateNewGame mapping to `"new"` all three requests work. But `POST: /games/new` is no RESTful URL Layout and I would rather avoid it. I don't understand why I get this behaviour and how I may solve it. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: According to this (https://faithfull.me/overriding-spring-data-rest-repositories/) you should not have a ResquestMapping at class level.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. I got that from here as a "Convention" https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#server.entity-links.controller The behaviour is very strange anyway. Do you think this could be considered a bug?

Comment: @marcellorvalle May you formulate this as an answer, then I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I really don't know if it is a bug, I never worked with RepositoryRestController. Unfortunately I don't have my development machine with me.  Fell free to post a correct answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use @BasePathAwareControllerannotation above your controller to preserve default spring data rest paths and add new custom path base on your need. Although overwrite default spring data rest path.

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class CustomGameController {
private final GameService gameService;

public CustomGameController(GameService gameService) {
    this.gameService = gameService;
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = 
 "application/hal+json")
public PersistentEntityResource generateNewGame(@RequestBody CreateGameDTO 
createGameDTO, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
    Game game = gameService.generateNewGame(createGameDTO);
    return assembler.toFullResource(game);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but since I am not longer working on this project I am unable to verify the answer. Maybe I will come back to it.

Comment: `RepositoryRestController` inherits from `BasePathAwareController`, so the trick to keep the automagically generated endpoints is, as mentioned in comments of the question, not to use `ResquestMapping` at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something we usually do in Linux. Set a fake path and link to it.

```
POST /games     ==> [filter] request.uri.euqal("/games") && request.method==POST
 ==> Redirect /new/games
```

What you see also is `/games`.

Don't use `/games/new`, it may be conflict with things inner Spring.